# C# creating an HTML line with escaping

Tags: c#, html, properties

I'm creating a loop in which each line is a pretty long HTML line on the page. I've tried various combinations of @ and """ but I just can't seem to get the hang of it
This is what I've got now, but the single quotes are giving me problems on the page, so I want to change all the single quotes to double quotes, just like a normal HTML line would use them for properties in the elements:

```
sOutput += "<div class='item link-item " + starOrBullet + "'><a href='" + appSet + linkID + "&TabID=" + tabID + "' target=’_blank’>" + linkText + "</a></div>";
```

```
variables are:
starOrBullet 
appSet
LinkID
tabID (NOT $TabID=)
linkText

BTW, appSet="http://linktracker.swmed.org:8020/LinkTracker/Default.aspx?LinkID="
Can someone help me here?
```

Comment: What are the values of your variables?

Comment: You can escape dbl quotes in a regular string with `\"` or in verbatim string literals with `""`. Example: `sOutput += $"<div class=\"item link-item {starOrBullet}\"><a href=\"{appSet}{linkID}\" &TabID=\"{tabID}\" target=\"_blank\">{linkText}</a></div>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes (") with `\"`

For your case:

```
sOutput += "<div class=\"item link-item " + starOrBullet + "\"><a href=\"" + appSet + linkID + "&TabID=" + tabID + "\" target=’_blank’>" + linkText + "</a></div>";
```

If you concat many strings, you should use StringBuilder for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a verbatim string and escape a double quote with a double quote. So it will be a double double quote.

```
tring mystring = @"This is \t a ""verbatim"" string";
```

You can also make your string shorter by doing the following:

Method 1

```
string mystring = @"First Line
                    Second Line
                    Third Line";
```

Method 2

```
string mystring = "First Line \n" +
                  "Second Line \n" +
                  "Third Line \n";
```

Method 3

```
var mystring = String.Join(
               Environment.NewLine,
               "First Line",
               "Second Line",
               "Third Line");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make habit to use C# class to generate Html instead concatenation. Please find below code to generate Html using C#.

Check this link for more information 
https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2014/june/generating-html-string-in-c/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter

Find below code for your question

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string starOrBullet = "star-link";
            string appSet = "http://linktracker.swmed.org:8020/LinkTracker/Default.aspx?LinkID=";
            string LinkID = "2";
            string tabID = "1";
            string linkText = "linkText_Here";
            string sOutput = string.Empty;

            StringBuilder sbControlHtml = new StringBuilder();

            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
                {
                    //Generate container div control  
                    HtmlGenericControl divControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    divControl.Attributes.Add("class", string.Format("item link-item {0}",starOrBullet));                    

                    //Generate link control  
                    HtmlGenericControl linkControl = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    linkControl.Attributes.Add("href", string.Format("{0}{1}&TabID={2}",appSet,LinkID,tabID));
                    linkControl.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
                    linkControl.InnerText = linkText;

                    //Add linkControl to container div  
                    divControl.Controls.Add(linkControl);

                    //Generate HTML string and dispose object   
                    divControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
                    sbControlHtml.Append(stringWriter.ToString());
                    divControl.Dispose();
                }
            }

            sOutput = sbControlHtml.ToString();
        }
```